# D3 line graph with real time scale sliding out of graph container

Tags: d3.js

I'm having a problem with my time scale line graph in "real time", which is going out of graph container: See full code in action also here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matjazzeleznik/h482j06d/)

**What I want to achieve:** Currently I have static/dummy data for `temp` and `time` which will be later populated via AJAX / JSON. Temp represents temperature and time represents Date in milliseconds which I get with custom `setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:50.000Z",0, true)` function (I saw that d3 has some time functions, but I didn't manage to dig in yet).

So basically I want to show in 5 second interval on X-axis the temperature with max. 6 ticks on axis, but as described, my LINE is moving out of graph container. **More of the idea you can see in my code below** ("working" example on above link of jsfiddle):

```
   <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <div id="visualisation"></div>
   <script>
   /*
    * inputDate: date in ISO format
    * offset: offset time
    * isMili: true returns milliseconds, false returns Date object
    */
    function setDateTimezone(inputDate, offset, isMili){
        var d = new Date(inputDate);
        var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
        if(isMili){
            var nd = +new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
        }else{
            var nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
        }
        return nd;
    }

    var data = [
        {
            "temp": -5.0,
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",0, true)
        },                                                     
        {                                                      
            "temp": 18.0,                                      
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:05.000Z",0, true)
        },                                                     
        {                                                      
            "temp": 22.0,                                      
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:10.000Z",0, true)
        },                                                     
        {                                                      
            "temp": 17.0,                                      
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:15.000Z",0, true)
        },                                                     
        {                                                      
            "temp": 26.0,                                      
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:20.000Z",0, true)
        },                                                     
        {                                                     
            "temp": 20.0,                                      
            "time": setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:25.000Z",0, true)
        }
    ];

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 35, bottom: 30, left: 35};
    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",0, false), setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:25.000Z",0, false)])
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-10,30])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Hh %Mm %Ss"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        //.interpolate('basis') //krivulja smooth
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.temp); });


    var svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var axisX = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

    var axisY = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Temperature °C");


    var path = svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

    //temporary data that automatically adds in tick() function new temperature and new date for testing
    var cTemp = 30.0;
    var cDate = setDateTimezone("2016-02-09T00:00:25.000Z",0, true);

    tick();

    function tick() {

        // push a new data point onto the back
        cDate +=5000;
        cTemp++;

        //add new data
        data.push({
            "temp": cTemp,                                      
            "time": cDate
        });

        //remove first
        data.shift();

        // update domain
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.temp; }));

        // Slide x-axis left
        svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .ease('linear')
            .call(xAxis); 

        // Slide y-axis up/down 
        svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .ease('linear')
            .call(yAxis);

        var historyTime = (data[0].time) - 5000;
        console.log(historyTime);

        // redraw line
        path
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("transform", null)
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(new Date(historyTime)) + ")")
            .each("end", tick);

    }
    </script>
```

and **CSS style** (if needed):

```
svg {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #337ab7;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

So any help will be appreciated, what have I missed or what am I doing wrong.. Thanks!

Comment: So the line that we can see right now going out of the container you would like it just not to be displayed right?

Comment: Yes, not to be displayed, and on the right side should go smoothly like in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070 Basically it has to be shifted to the right for 5 seconds, that the right side of the line updates outside of the container, that it doesnt look like bow, when you can see this "jump" when the new data is added..

Comment: What is your problem exactly with using the code you just sent a link to?

Comment: Line of a graph should not go over Y-axis and the on the right side of the graph, when line changes (when new data is added) this "adding" effect should not be seen. Line should be updated outside of the visible part, to get this smooth effect as you can see on the link in previous comment.

Comment: Yeah my question was what is your problem in using the same principle as the link of previous comment?

Comment: If I would know, where is the problem, I wouldn't posted this question on Stackoverflow. I can't get it to work with my code as I want to (described in question and comments) to work like example in comment above.

Comment: Ok so here is a in progress version : https://jsfiddle.net/vb7do4v8/
I have way less time than I thought I'd have.
In the example it solves the adding as a smooth thing, I removed the y axis live modification cause I couldn't get it to work quickly, but will try to make it happen when I find time.
Also there is still the line overflow even if I am pretty sure there must be a simple way to remove it, haven't had time to do it either so far.